# query select employee name inside manager name in datatable child row

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

It seems that my select is wrong. What I want in the datatables is that every supervisor name can have a child row containing an employee name. But what I get is this:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "name_supervisor": "Alex",
  "name": "testStaff4",
  "manager_id": "2",
  "role_id": "1"
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "name_supervisor": "Andika",
  "name": "testStaff1",
  "manager_id": "1",
  "role_id": "1"
}
```

This is my query:

```
$supervisors = DB::table('supervisors')->join('users','users.manager_id','=','supervisors.id')
            ->select(['supervisors.id','supervisors.name_supervisor','users.name','users.manager_id','users.role_id'])
            ->where('users.role_id',1)
            ->orWhere('users.role_id',null)
            ->groupBy('supervisors.name_supervisor');
            return Datatables::of($supervisors)->make(true);
```

This is my js datatable with child row:

```
function format ( d ) {
                // `d` is the original data object for the row
                return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td>Name:</td>'+
                        '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</table>';
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table =  $('#ajax_data').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ajax: 'supervisor/json',
                    dom: '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lip><"clear">',
                    columnDefs: [{"className": "text-center", "targets": "_all"}],
                    columns: [
                        {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "data":           null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                        },
                        { data: 'name_supervisor', name: 'supervisors.name_supervisor' }
                    ]
                });

            } );
```

I have `manager_id` in the users table which is a foreign key from the `supervisors` table. I want to get a json output like this:

```
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name_supervisor": "Andika",
      "name": "testStaff1","testStaff2","testStaff3"
      "manager_id": "1",
      "role_id": "1"
    },
```

Comment: Add couple of test database records as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use GROUP CONCAT on user name as below

```
    $supervisors = DB::table('supervisors')->join('users','users.manager_id','=','supervisors.id')
            ->select(['supervisors.id','supervisors.name_supervisor',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(users.name) as name'),'users.manager_id','users.role_id'])
            ->where('users.role_id',1)
            ->orWhere('users.role_id',null)
            ->groupBy('supervisors.name_supervisor');
            return Datatables::of($supervisors)->make(true);
```

You can see  the name is grouped using [Group_Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function and you have more options on sepearator and order by class to make it suit for your needs.

Refer [Laravel Query Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) to use aggregate or string functions used as you can use it mysql query.